# cURL request not accepting cookies, results in endless redirect

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I am trying to build a cURL request to download a pdf. I am getting the "Error:Maximum (100) redirects followed" error and believe it is due to a cookie issue. Here's the relevant code from my cURL request:

```
$cookie_file = "/home/mrpeanut/php/cookie.txt"
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, implode(':', $arrayCiphers));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($cookie_file));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath($cookie_file));
```

And have also tried `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '-'` (from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#30906)), all without luck. The pdf downloads just fine using a browser. However, it downloads even if I disable all cookies using the Web Developer toolbar (so maybe that's not my true issue?).

Comment: does the site you're doing this download from require a login? You'd therefore need to be sending ALL of the cookies that your browser is, especially things like session cookies/auth tokens.

Comment: If there is session based on cookies, `add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);` There are reports that infinite redirects also stem form wrong url - for example http instead of https, or mixed case url

Comment: No, it does not require a login.

Comment: @n-dru I added `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);` and still no luck. I downloaded the file with a browser and copied the download url and that's what I'm using in cURL. Would cURL be changing the protocol or case?

Comment: have you checked where it is redirected to?

Comment: Well, I download the file in Chrome and copy that url and that's what I'm using in my curl request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send CURLOPT_COOKIE with the value of your PHPSESSID. That is how the server is going to identify the cookie.

You should add this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/');
```

Comment: I am still getting a max redirect error with your code. If I disable `FOLLOWLOCATION`, the result is an "Object moved to here." (indicating a redirect). However, the url I'm providing works fine in a browser.

Comment: Did you use php function session_start() at the top of your file ?

Comment: My file starts as `<?php session_start(); $url = "https://some.domain.com/etc"`. Is that correct?